# Probability that one Gaussian RV exceeds all others

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo, order-statistics

Imagine we have $k$ Gaussian RVs $$
X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) \text{ for } i=1, \ldots, k
$$
and we sample from each of them independently to produce a vector, $\vec{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_k)$.

For one of the Gaussian RVs, say $X_j$, I am interested in computing the probability that it exceeds all others, i.e. $$
\Pr\left\{ \cap_{i\not= j} \, X_j > X_i \right\}.
$$

I know I can use Monte Carlo sampling to estimate this probability. But are there any closed-form analytical methods or approximations?

Comment: This has been asked several times (but is difficult to search for).  The general answer to the analytical question is no when $k\gt 2.$  So far, nobody has proposed approximations, most likely because they depend very much on $k$ and details of the $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i.$  For instance, there is an obvious approximation when $\mu_j$ exceeds all the other $\mu_i$ by a substantial amount relative to the SDs of their differences and another obvious one when there is a $\mu_i$ much greater than $\mu_j.$ Can you describe your circumstances more specifically?

Comment: Sadly, what I wrote describes the circumstances as narrowly as possible. I am trying to compute the choice probabilities for a multivariate probit choice model with more than 2 choices.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but if you can do it for $k=2$ and the variables are independent, then you can factor it as a product, no?